# Jquery success function error

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and having some trouble trying to get the success function from working properly. I have been trying my best to read some peoples questions regarding the same issue and have applied the changes required but cannot seem to get it working properly.

If someone could please point me in the right direction.

```
/**
 * Add user
 */
function display_reg_success() {

    alert('Display function worked');

    window.location.replace('/forums/usercp.php');

}


function add_user(data_string) {

    alert('called add user');

    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: '/index.php',
        data: data_string,
        success: function (response) {
            display_reg_success();
        }

    });

}

function user_email_exists(username, email) {

    $.get("/verify.php", {
        username: username,
        email: email
    },

    function (data) {

        alert('Data:' + data);

        if (data == 'username') {

            $('#username_taken_error').show();
            $('#username').focus();

        }
        else if (data == 'email') {

            $('#email_taken_error').show();
            $('#email').focus();

        }
        else if (data == 'username|email') {

            $('#username_taken_error').show();
            $('#email_taken_error').show();
            $('#username').focus();

        }
        else if (data == 'true') {

            alert('true');

            return true;

        }

    });

}


/** Regform - Paul  */

$(function () {

    $('.submit_reg_field').click(function () {

        $('.error_form').hide();

        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

        //required
        var username = $("input#username").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var confirm_email = $("input#email2").val();
        var password = $("input#password").val();
        var password2 = $("input#password2").val();
        var agree_terms = $('#agree:checked').val();

        /*
                    //options
                    var hideemail = $("#hideemail:checked").val();
                    var receivepms = $("#receivepms:checked").val();
                    var pmnotice = $("#pmnotice:checked").val();
                    var emailpmnotify = $("#emailpmnotify:checked").val();
                    var invisible = $("#invisible:checked").val();
                    var timezone = $("#timezone option:selected").val();
                    */

        if (username == '') {
            $('#username_error').show();
            $('#username').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (password == '') {
            $('#password_error').show();
            $('#password').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (password.length < 6) {
            $('#password_length_error').show();
            $('#password').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (password2 == '') {
            $('#confirm_password_error').show();
            $('#password2').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (password != password2) {
            $('#confirm_password_match_error').show();
            $('#password').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (email == '') {
            $('#email_error').show();
            $('#email').focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
                $('#email_valid_error').show();
                $('#email').focus();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (confirm_email == '') {
            $('#confirm_email_error').show();
            $('#confirm_email').focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (email != confirm_email) {
            $('#confirm_email_match_error').show();
            $('#email').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (agree_terms != "1") {
            $('#agree_error').show();
            return false;
        }

        var data_string = 'register=true&username=' + username + '&email=' + email + '&email2=' + confirm_email + '&password=' + password + '&password2=' + password2;

        if (user_email_exists(username, email)) {

            /*+ '&hideemail=' + hideemail + '&receivepms=' + receivepms + '&pmnotice=' + pmnotice + '&emailnotify=' + emailnotify + '&invisible=' + invisible + '&timezone=' + timezone*/

            add_user(data_string);

        }

        return false;

    });

});
```

The form

```
<table id="reg_table" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">Username</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="text_field" id="username" value="" />
            <span class="error_form" id="username_error">This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error_form" id="username_taken_error">That username is already in use.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="text_field" value="" />
            <span class="error_form" id="password_error">This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error_form" id="password_length_error">The password is too short.</span>
            <span class="error_form" id="confirm_password_match_error">Passwords do not match.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" id="password2" class="text_field" value="" />
            <span class="error_form" id="confirm_password_error">This field is required.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="text_field" value="" />
            <span class="error_form" id="email_error">This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error_form" id="email_valid_error">This is not a valid email.</span>
            <span class="error_form" id="email_taken_error">That email is already in use.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Confirm Email</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="email2" class="text_field" value="" />
            <span class="error_form" id="confirm_email_error">This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error_form" id="confirm_email_match_error">Emails do not match.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">I agree to the
            <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="agree" value="1" />
            <span class="error_form" id="agree_error">You must agree to the Terms and Conditions.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="submit_reg_field" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[/html]

Comment: what exactly is the issue? is the said function not executed, is it malfunctioning?

Comment: Yes the last function called is not working display_reg_success() I have checked all of the other functions the email/username check works well and the user is registered it's just the redirect is not working.

Comment: check edits to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
window.location = '/forums/usercp.php';
```

btw, checkout some form validation plugins for jQuery

EDIT: i'll show how the flow should be

```
/**
 * Add user
 */
var display_reg_success = function() { //scoping
    console.log('Display function worked'); //console is better debugging tool
    window.location.replace('/forums/usercp.php');
}


var add_user = function(data) {
    console.log('called add user');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/index.php',
        data: data, //see notes on serialization below
        success: display_reg_success    
    });

}

var user_email_exists = function(data) {

    $.get("/verify.php", data,
    function (response) {
        console.log('Response:',response);
        if (response== 'username') {
               //OMIT
        }
        else if (response== 'true') {
            console.log('true');

            add_user(data);
        }

    });

}


/** Regform - Paul  */

$(function () {

    $('.submit_reg_field').click(function () {

        $('.error_form').hide();

        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

        //required
        var username = $("input#username").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var confirm_email = $("input#email2").val();
        var password = $("input#password").val();
        var password2 = $("input#password2").val();
        var agree_terms = $('#agree:checked').val();

         //validation

        //notes on serialization: better make an object and let jquery serialize it,
        //i didnt seen any prevention code from entering an `&` into username field
        //and so introduce a security hole
        var data = {
            'register':true,
            'username':username,
            'email':email,
            'email2':confirm_email,
            'password':password
            //'password2': password //same is password, omit
            };

        user_email_exists(data);

        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out! I have a problem as the data being passed to the reg form php is not correct as it's only ending up being the username/email response from the checker script.

Comment: ah names collision, lemme fix

Answer (score 1):

`user_email_exists` makes an asynchronous Ajax call, it is impossible for that call to return a value to the server like you coded your function.

Comment: Ok, so what would be the best solution to this problem? The function does return true and the add_user function is called so not sure what you mean there?

Comment: Clearly websites have reg forms like this and all functions are being called it's only the last function which isn't doing anything!!

Comment: @user1559334 user_email_exists is always returning false, check it; to fix call `add_user` from within the callback of `$.get("/verify.php"`

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated in a comment above, the redirect is not working.

This is why...

```
window.location.replace('/forums/usercp.php');
```

should be...

```
window.location.replace('forums/usercp.php');
```

You have an absolute path when you probably want a relative one.

Answer (score -2):

Add some `console.log(response)` or alert in different lines  in your code and verify your console